# Is there a way to send app statistics to play console?

Tags: android

I know that when app crashes a bug report is sent to my developer console.
Now I'd like to add a statistics usage function: for example each week app gathers my app's preferences settings and send them to my dev console. This way I could see what users like more and, on the other hand, what has to be improved.

Is it possible with some android function? I know I could do something like send an email, or make an hidden connection to my server but I'd like a more "standard" way (moreover these hidden methods could not be liked by some user)...moreover error logs are sent so there IS a mechanism, problem is if I can attach to it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not the developer console, but you can use **Google Analytics** for that. There is an API to use it with Android, explained here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/

It's up to you, what exactly you're gonna track, but it's very easy and for dealing with the statistics you have all the power of Google Analytics at hand.

EDIT: For best results with least effort, you should use the [EasyTracker](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#eztracker) library, which makes sure that communication with the server is done in a separate thread; otherwise you will experience 'hickups' in the UI.